# How to create a log file that displays the names of files and the contents of it

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a BAT file that displays the file names of all the CSV files in a specific folder into a log file. It also displays the contents of those CSV files.

```
dir /b > MM.LOG
type *.csv >> MM.LOG
```

The way it is outputting is:

> ```
> File1 Name
> File2 Name
> File1 Content
> File2 Content
> ```

Is there a way to get it to display as:

> ```
> File1 Name / File1 Content
> File2 Name / File2 Content
> ```

An additional question, the "log" file seems to be saving as a .txt instead of .LOG. How can I fix this?

Comment: Type with a wildcard will always output the filename preceding the content. Do you want to have every content line prefixed with the file name?

Comment: 1. The `dir` command line needed to be changed to `dir /B *.csv` to not include files other than `.csv`. 2. Do you literally want to have file name, followed by `/`, followed by contents?

Comment: Yes, literally file name followed by the contents on every line. I can omit the /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`type` command](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html), when wild-cards like `?` and `*` are used, returns the name or path of each typed file at the *STDERR* stream, which could be [redirected](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to the *STDOUT* stream:

```cmd
type *.csv > MM.LOG 2>&1
```

The term `> MM.LOG`, equivalent to `1> MM.LOG`, redirects data at stream `1` (*STDOUT*) to the log file. `2>&1` redirects data at stream `2` (*STDERR*) to the same target as for stream `1`, hence `MM.LOG`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This gave me the output I wanted. 
Would you mind explaining this a little bit more? 
What does the 2>&1 mean?

Comment: I tried to briefly explain what happens in my answer; see also the [redirection article](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) I linked...

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.csv') do for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%b in (`type %%a`) do echo %%a / %%b >> MM.LOG
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, when I tried this it did not even create a log file.